# Creating relationships between items in a Knockout.js model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/brandondurham/g3exx/

**How can I create relationships between various observableArrays in my model?** For instance, in my model I have a `cartItems` array, and each item in that array has a nested `itemFreebies` array as well as an `itemType` property. Customers only get free items when they have a subscription in their cart (`"itemType" : "subscription"`) and, as such, when that subscription is removed I need to remove all other cart items' freebies, preferably with a nice fadeOut animation.

What is the best way to create these types of conditional relationships?

This is the object I'm using in my model:

```
{
    "cartItems" : [
        {
            "itemName" : "Product 1",
            "itemDesc" : "Product 1 description",
            "itemType" : "subscription",
            "itemPrice" : 299,
            "itemFreebies" : false
        }, {
            "itemName" : "Product 2",
            "itemDesc" : "Product 2 description",
            "itemType" : "desktop",
            "itemPrice" : 4499,
            "itemFreebies" : [{
                "freebieName" : "Product 2 freebie",
                "freebieDesc" : "Product 2 freebie description",
                "freebieOriginalPrice" : 99
            }]
        }, {
            "itemName" : "Product 3",
            "itemDesc" : "Product 3 description",
            "itemType" : "desktop",
            "itemPrice" : 8999,
            "itemFreebies" : [{
                "freebieName" : "Product 3 freebie",
                "freebieDesc" : "Product 3 freebie description",
                "freebieOriginalPrice" : 99
            }]
        }, {
            "itemName" : "Product 4",
            "itemDesc" : "Product 4 description",
            "itemType" : "desktop",
            "itemPrice" : 99,
            "itemFreebies" : [{
                "freebieName" : "Product 4 freebie",
                "freebieDesc" : "Product 4 freebie description",
                "freebieOriginalPrice" : 99
            }]
        }, {
            "itemName" : "Product 5",
            "itemDesc" : "Product 5 description",
            "itemType" : "webfont",
            "itemPrice" : 49,
            "itemFreebies" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
$(function () {
    ​var CartViewModel = {
        var self = this;

        self.cartItems = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.eligibleForFreebies = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.cartItems(), function(cartItem) {
                // I forgot the () after itemType in the original post
                return (cartItem.itemType() === 'subscription');
            });
            // Note: ko.utils.arrayFirst will either return the item in 
            //      question, or it will return undefined or null… 
            //      I forget which, but either will result in 
            //      eligibleForFreebies evaluating to false
        });
    };

    var Product = function() {
        var self = this;

        self.itemName = ko.observable();
        self.itemDesc = ko.observable();
        self.itemType = ko.observable();
        self.itemPrice = ko.observable();
        self.itemFreebies = ko.observableArray([]);
    };

    var Freebie = function() {
        var self = this;

        self.freebieName = ko.observable();
        self.freebieDesc = ko.observable();
        self.freebieOriginalPrice = ko.observable();
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new CartViewModel());
    // load data
});
```

​

Load Products into the cartItems observableArray in the CartViewModel.

The dependent observable (ko.computed) value `eligibleForFreebies` will determine whether or not the Freebies should be allowed.

It's likely that you wouldn't even need to remove the freebies from the Products when the cart is not eligible for them – simply check `eligibleForFreebies` and include or exclude the freebies from the display, invoice, etc.  (This might save you the headache of retrieving freebies after the user adds the subscription, but I suppose that depends on your scenario.)

Hope this helps to get you started on this one, but let me know if you have any questions.

**UPDATE:** I [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yUpWe/29/) and reworked your code a bit...  well, I mostly moved it around, but I did add some functionality.

Notice that if you delete the subscription item from the cart, all the freebies disappear from the cart display--but I didn't delete them from the objects!

If one adds a method for re-adding a subscription item to the cart, the freebies would reappear.

Please have a look when you have a chance, and let me know if you'd like me to explain anything.

Comment: Hiya Jimmy. Thanks so much for the suggestion. I'm not completely clear on how to add the items from the `cartItems` array using the `Products` and `Freebie` objects. Here's a jsFiddle of my existing code: http://jsfiddle.net/brandondurham/g3exx/

Comment: Hi Jimmy. Thank so much for putting that together. One question: Do you know why the `beforeRemoveAnimation` on the freebies?

Comment: So I actually do need to remove those freebies objects when the subscription is removed as I'll be sending this JSON to the serve when the user goes to check out. It's safe, though, as adding the subscription back happens on another page. I don't have to worry about capturing that here.

Comment: `beforeRemoveAnimation` is on freebies only because you had `beforeRemove` on `itemFreebies` in your fiddle, i.e. just a translation from what you had :-)

Comment: Oops... the comment regarding `beforeRemoveAnimation` is missing some text. I was asking why the animation isn't working on the freebies. It's only working on the root level elements.

Comment: ah, I see... well, I looked into that question, and I both figured out why the animation wasn't working and changed the solution so that the animation does work.  Problem #1 was that I forgot that the `beforeRemove` binding is one that is *specific* (AFAIK) to the `template` binding, and I had `beforeRemove` in a virtual element.  Problem #2 is that my trick for hiding the freebies by using the `eligibleForFreebies` flag, of course, wasn't *removing* the freebies!  Once I addressed both issues, the animation worked as expected.  My fiddle now contains the updated code.